# Websites reliability database

Tags: data-request, reliability, news

It is a bit subjective, but we can all agree that guardian.com is more reliable than clickhole.com
Here I define "reliability" as the tendency to publish information that are considered true by the majority of academics in the relevant field, and the tendency to not publish information that is later found to be erroneous.

Is there a database giving websites a **reliability score**?
The score could be decided by experts or rated by users or somehow generated (for instance by seeing how often the website is used in Wikipedia citations).

Sometimes very different publications are hosted under the same domain name, so it might make sense to have a finer granularity (by URL?) if needed.

The database should cover at least websites than market themselves as news websites or reference websites.

*Such a database already exists here but it is not open data, and it is only available as a web interface or browser extensions, not available as a full download: http://www.lemonde.fr/verification/*

Comment: How do you define reliability? If you are looking for the safety of a site (wrt malware), virustotal provides this. In terms of accuracy of information presented that's a wide-open topic that's hard to narrow down, and a number of organizations (eg: Knight Foundation, YCombinator) are currently asking for proposals along those lines. Frequency of citation or linking may already exist from sources like alexa and google but some of these are not freely accessible. If you can clarify what you're looking for a little I might be able to provide a more useful answer.

Comment: @DGinzberg: Clarified, thanks! As you wrote, Alexa and Google do not publish their data (and also they don't focus on reliability, for instance they are probably more interested in popularity).